# Get Activity in Service

Tags: android, service, xamarin.android

The code below works. But I know it is not the right way of doing things and I would like to know what is the right way to do this. I have a Keyboard service that that displays GIF images in a ListView. But the ListView needs an activity to show it. How do I get an activity in my ListView? (I have already tried casting the service as an activity. I get an invalid cast exception)

```
  public override View OnCreateInputView()
  {
          View imageKeyboardView = (View)LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ImageKeyboard, null);
                listView = imageKeyboardView.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.List); // get reference to the ListView in the layout
                Activity act = MainActivity.Instance;
                // populate the listview with data
                listView.Adapter = new ImageKeyboardAdapter(act, listOfIconUris);
                listView.ItemClick += OnListItemClick;  // to be defined
                return imageKeyboardView;
  }
```

Comment: If it's a service, then you can use it as the context. Service inherits ContextWrapper which inherits Context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [CurrentActivityPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin) to get your `Application`’s current `Activity` that is being displayed.

Comment: I've used it before but forgot all about it. Thanks.